# message dialog error

Tags: java, swing

I get this error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method showMessageDialog(<anonymous javax.swing.AbstractAction>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int)
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

```
 exitAction = new
 AbstractAction("Esci") {

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             if (rcStatus ==1) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
 "Thread running. Choose STOP before
 exit",
                     "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


         }
          else {

                 System.exit(0);}

             }
         };
         exitAction.putValue(Action.NAME,
         "Exit");

         exitAction.putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION,"Close");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in `JOptionPane` with that signature. Are you sure that the `this` you're passing in is an `AbstractAction`, which is not a `Component`. For `showMessageDialog()`, [these are your options](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component%2C%20java.lang.Object%29).

I think you want [`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     String title,
                                     int messageType)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component%2C%20java.lang.Object%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20int%29). If you don't have a suitable parent component to pass in, pass `null` instead of `this`:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread running. Choose STOP before exit", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method call, `this` refers to the anonymous class that you are creating (that extends AbstractAction).

If this code is inside of a Component, such as:

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
...
(your code)
```

then you can change your method call to:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MyComponent.this, "Thread running", ...
```

`MyComponent.this` refers to the outer class object.

Comment: It is part of a private void createActions() {.....} Should I rewrite the whole code? thanks

Comment: you can use ProgAud.this instead of this.  The type of ProgAud.this is a JFrame that you can use in the method call.  The type of 'this' is an AbstractAction which you can't.

Comment: It works perfectly ...thanks a lot . I also have another question which doesn't deal with message dialogs ...Should I open a new thread?

Comment: if it's unrelated, yep, ask a new question.